# Find the Prime Signature

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, factoring

The [Prime Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_signature) of a number is the list of the exponents of the prime factors of a number, sorted in descending order (exponents of `0` are ignored). Inspired by [Combo Class](https://www.youtube.com/@ComboClass)'s "[The Magnificent Patterns of Prime Signatures](https://youtu.be/2xLMhB_cTgc)" video.

For example, the prime factorization of `6860` is `2 * 2 * 5 * 7 * 7 * 7`, or `2^2 + 5^1 + 7^3`. The exponents are `2`, `1`, and `3`, so the Prime Signature is `{3, 2, 1}`

## I/O

You will be given an integer on the interval `[1, 10,000,000]`.

You must output an array/list/vector or a string (in the format below) of the input's prime signature.

## Examples/Test Cases

| Numbers | Signature |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ∅ or {} |
| 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 | {1} |
| 4, 9, 25, 49, 121 | {2} |
| 6, 10, 14, 15, 21 | {1, 1} |
| 8, 27, 125, 343 | {3} |
| 12, 18, 20, 28 | {2, 1} |
| 16, 81, 625, 2401 | {4} |
| 24, 40, 54, 56 | {3, 1} |
| 30, 42, 66, 70 | {1, 1, 1} |
| 32, 243, 3125 | {5} |
| 36, 100, 196, 225 | {2, 2} |
| 12345 | {1, 1, 1} |
| 123456 | {6, 1, 1} |
| 1234567 | {1, 1} |
| 5174928 | {5, 4, 3} |
| 8388608 | {23} |
| 9999991 | {1} |

Note that these are not sets in the computer science sense because they can contain duplicate values and have an ordering (admittedly, some set implementations are ordered).

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the fewest bytes wins!

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 6 bytes

```apl
∨2⌷2⍭⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xbsMwDEX3nkIHkAGTkmV57pKuTS4QwHaXoMnQoZ0LBIFRB82QC2TKkCBLgO4@Ci/ifkkeIkDi1yM/yeVmldVfy9X6LWs@P5r3uqnHUXZnlp8/lv4q3WlsZfsr/V66b@kv0t@Hm5HtQfbH@esz3sXsZT62w1nRU3hZK6NVoVWpFSVktaq0YjCLSJyog8xxkSWkJuqhgjNUG2siI/SkkEA5@4Tg9qSVC3Vs82k2elkUFYiFi8jga@F3MJR5QhwsWNJgSiJxl7BMBcUTJTb2QbkHWUZdUGmraSFvvHd50lU89A8)

`∨` descending sort of…

`2⌷` the second row of…

`2⍭` the table of primes (in the first row) and their exponents (in the second row) of…

`⊢` the argument

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
∆ǐsṘ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiIbHkHPhuZgiLCIiLCIxMjM0NTYiXQ==)

So uh turns out the prime exponents built-in doesn't include 0s by complete accident - it's not a bug, just a consequence of how it's implemented and a different understanding of what a prime exponents built-in should do lol.

### Explained

```
∆ǐsṘ
∆ǐ   # prime exponents of the input
  s  # sorted
   Ṙ # reversed
```

Comment: Very good! You're missing two spaces, one in each of lines 3-4 of the explanation to keep the character layout, but I can't suggest that edit with the edit button since that change is not at least 6 characters.

Comment: @Samathingamajig I think the characters are misaligned because of the way the `ǐ` is rendered. I've noticed that happens sometimes when unicode characters aren't exactly monospace :/

Comment: @lyxal using a tab character solves the alignment issue

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
_YFSP
```

Try at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=_YFSP&inputs=5174928&version=22.7.4)!

#### Explanation

```
_YF   % Implicit input. Prime factor exponents without zeros
S     % Sort
P     % Flip. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 37 bytes

```factor
[ group-factors values [ >=< ] sort ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczLCsIwEEbhfZ/ifwEDilLvW3HTjbgqXYQ4raVpEmamgk8fpeL6fJzWOo2c77drddljtPo0ifuRxLRzEViR6AQSWfvQ/UjkBzESk@r7y4NiIA7kcSiKzbJc71bbXKPjOKXF//OyfiJBjfPpiGb@ocnOeg@TPw)

- `group-factors` Get the prime factorization of an integer as an assoc where keys are factors and values are exponents.
- `values` Get the exponents.
- `[ >=< ] sort` Sort into descending order.

Comment: A language with factor in its name is definitely appropriate for this challenge

Answer (score 5):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 27 bytes

```
n->-vecsort(-factor(n)[,2])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVBbCsIwEETwIEu_WkigebRNP-xFikgoVgRpQ62CZ_GnIOIhvImncbalgTCzszO7Ic9P8MP5cArTq6Xd-za20n07Wcn7sbn2wxjL1jdjP8RdUgu9TxbHb7P1IVwesSdZURjO3QgacRFRG_skEVQrQVqQEZQJKgQp1FZQCRWCBSoNKQemuGgp6Cw5AAfYZ6xhhssqjBqoEHKcZYe2KW9C3qKdATO0DbhFLAcvwI1mD2aZZey8lveWYJolpY1dIV8Rz8hUYUve6oxzeQpSzketnzFNC_4B)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 56 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔²ηＷ⊖θ¿﹪θη≦⊕η«≔⁰ζＷ¬﹪θη«≦⊕ζ≧÷ηθ»⊞υζ»≔⟦⟧ζＷ⁻υζＦ№υ⌈ι⊞ζ⌈ιＩζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY89T8MwEIZn51fceJaCBBUIUKaqXTqkqlgRg0nc@iTHbv1RUFF/u7GbAOrA6Pee5/Vdp4TrrNAprcw@hnUc3qXDA2@qufe0MzirQeXXhyItAZeyc3KQJsg@QxxoC9jaPmqLhwJyaMV@Mlfmlx07pPYSvio2zW9rOOWUTdVrG66reGHZP30X82/4QjsVMhGWdKReZr@GcgQ7V2wTvcI4Kuefs17fxmD6vCUT/Qhx2FoHuLDRhJK04pOGOCCVjS5dp6uwqTaOMroQPmDWm5Qe7h7vn2dP6eaovwE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the integer.

```
≔²η
```

Start trial division at `2`.

```
Ｗ⊖θ¿﹪θη≦⊕η
```

Until the integer has been reduced to `1`, keep incrementing the trial divisor until it divides the integer.

```
«≔⁰ζＷ¬﹪θη«≦⊕ζ≧÷ηθ»⊞υζ»
```

Calculate the multiplicity of the trial divisor and push it to the predefined empty list.

```
≔⟦⟧ζＷ⁻υζＦ№υ⌈ι⊞ζ⌈ιＩζ
```

Sort the list in descending order and output the result.

36 bytes by importing Python modules:

```
≔▷”8±J≧∕*}G⦃⬤t；⁼hsλ”ＮθＩ⮌▷SＥ▷listθ§θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DtSwxJyyxSEOpuDK3oFIvryQjNb@oUi8tMbkkvygzr0RJRyHaM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDM1ZTR6FQ05orACSr4ZxYXKIRlFqWWlScimRWflFJagpIq29iAUI4J7MYbF4hyAzHEs@8lNQKjUIdhUxNoKlAYP3/v6mhuYmlkcV/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔▷”8±J≧∕*}G⦃⬤t；⁼hsλ”Ｎθ
```

Use `sympy.ntheory.factorint` to get a dictionary of prime factors and their multiplicities.

```
Ｉ⮌▷SＥ▷listθ§θι
```

Extract the multiplicities, sort them, and output the reversed result.

This can be reduced to 26 bytes if you run the latest version of Charcoal locally:

```
Ｉ⮌▷SＥ▷”8±J≧∕*}G⦃⬤t；⁼hsλ”Ｎι
```

Unfortunately you can't try this online because the version of Charcoal on TIO can't enumerate dictionaries and the version of Charcoal on ATO can't import `sympy`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>6</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
Đϼ1\⇹ḋɔŞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARgA5/9weXT//8SQz7wxXOKHueG4i8mUxZ7//zE)

```
Đ            implicit input (n); duplicate top of stack
 ϼ           get the unique prime factors of n
  1\        remove any pesky 1s
     ⇹ḋ      get the prime factors of n (with duplicates)
       ɔ     count the number of occurrences of each unique prime factor
        Ş    sort in descending order
```

Comment: Try the `1` testcase. This outputs `[1]` when it should output `[]` or similar

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 77 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=2,w)=>n%i?n-!w?f(n,i+1).concat(w||[]).sort((a,b)=>b-a):[]:f(n/i,i,-~w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcqxDsIgFIXh3bdwMOFGwFDrYBPsgzQdKIK52kBTiCSm8dFFHByMZ/zOf1V3FfSMU2TOn03OVhJHUVY0gTy5DbaOrVNrP7gVwLV3WkWSlqXrgQc/R0IUHUo7MAVN1zcl3SFFyp4JcsmDHw0f/YVYIgBWv1L/iaj29aFofvkpYrkyC1HpGwv4MPL43Rs)

Thank Arnauld for -1 or real`[]`ify(was two solutions)

Comment: How do 9999991 took my 10G+ RAM?

Comment: For the `1` test case, this returns `[undefined]`, length 1, which is different from an empty array `[]`, length 0

Comment: I think you can use `n-!w` instead of `n-1|w`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 71 bytes

`-4` bytes for both code segments thanks to `Neil`.
`-8` bytes thanks to `corvus_192`

```python
lambda n:sorted(factorint(n).values())[::-1]
from sympy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVDLboMwELzzFXuEyonwAzBIOfcj0hxoAwpSsBE4lfiWXJCi9p_6Lb10FhpL1oxnZ3atvX8Pc7h4tzymw9vXLbQ7-_N6rfv3c02umvwYmnPc1h_Bj50LsUv2n_X11kxxkhyraidPUTv6nqa5H-a9C5fGjzN1_YDgy3-739aP5KhzdJSClCAtKBNUCJJ4G0ElVAgGKBWkHJjioiShs2QBHGCfNpoZLqswKqBEyHKWHcqkPAl5g3IGzFDW4AaxHLwA14o96KW3tutYnluCKZak0uYJ-RPxjUwWpuSpVlubpyDleuSpioiGdVMTdpVE2wqWZcM_)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 128 bytes

Uses a recursive helper [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152433/110265) to calculate the prime factors of a number.
Failed on the test cases `1234567, 9999991` due to `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

```python
lambda n:sorted(Counter(f(n)).values())[::-1]
f=lambda n,i=2:n//i*[0]and f(n,i+1)if n%i else[i]+f(n//i)
from collections import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDdSsMwGMXbPsXnhazZMtf8tGsLuxJ8idqL2qYY6JLSZOIQwffwZiD6Tvo0flkZGAjn5Hzn5IR8fI9H_2TN6dPtHr4Ovl_nP-9Ds3_sGjCls5NXXXxnD8arKe5jQ8jtczMclIsJqcpyzeqo3138VO94aTYbvaySujEdYIDqFSO6B3OjQQ1OVbpeoYwmEvWT3UNrh0G1XlvjQO9HbFzO7_i9Sns7gQFtoGIUOAVBIaWwpcDwLCkUqKIgERlHKUNMcOOIoR6kHCEEgk9IERjuoKKRIzIM5SEbHFwmoQnzEscpYopjgVxiLEO-RS548OBdYr72XBt6C2Q8SIwLeYHsgviMlG1lEVpzkedZgqQ4L1aXEYCfjgEAxkkbH7vw3XhWL60a_f9Jv7hv9KA6sAa8ch7axil4NW_XCxLNv3c6zfgH)

Comment: Reversing the output of `sorted` using `[::-1]` saves 4 bytes over `,reverse=1`.

Comment: 67 bytes: `from sympy import*`

Comment: Very interesting use of itertools :p

Answer (score 4):

## [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org), 45 bytes

```sagemath
lambda n:sorted(e for p,e in factor(n))[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdUNtqhDAQfRf8h3lLAlnYXLysYH_E9cG6kcq2KiYLS8V_7yRmW-hAMueczC0z1Nc0-ey-3m8dTJWdV2du1MAwr7BwA-MEQ9e7eaUTY01VnUSbJmnijHVQAxUcJAfNIedQchBIBEKJijrjQa5yryudRfeiecEhE4W-SEwsVVnmZwSXYIKliXkupsdhfJum5dAIf8mAsIT3KiiR6KBE4iMizGKQ_Kfnf_A3NHzlqKqOljhI_2H6u1n9HOT6kIXuCYeAhCL47lfljlV9jwv1q-Hwmp5VaQJoFtMH6tjBlnWcHB3I5nY4vcFmd9him8bWtWl3wn4AEbhkqA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆE¹ƇṢU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm@uhncfaH@5cFPr//38LYwsLMwMLAA)

A port of my vyxal answer.

### Explained

```
ÆE¹ƇṢU
ÆE     # Prime exponents of the input - contains 0s
  ¹Ƈ   # so filter out those 0s
    Ṣ  # sort the list
     U # and reverse it
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>58</s> <s>51</s> 47 bytes

```matlab
@(n)-sort(-diff(find(diff([0 factor(n) n<2]))))
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI09Ttzi/qERDNyUzLU0jLTMvRQPMijZQSEtMLskvAqpQyLMxitUEgv9pGoZGxiamZpr/AQ)

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(n)                                              % Define anonymous function
                             factor(n)            % Prime factors of input
                          [0                      % Prepend 0 and...
                                       n<2]       % ...postpend 1 if n<2, 0 otherwise
                     diff(                 )      % Consecutive differences
                find(                       )     % Indices of nonzeros
           diff(                             )    % Consecutive differences
    -sort(-                                   )   % Negate, sort, negate
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ó0K{R
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8GQD7@qg///NLMwMAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##LY27DcJAEERbsRy/4PZz57vIBZCRIgKQCIgIkJAscgqAkuiERo4FeYMdzc7o7eV6OJ5P/bbM4/B5PIdxXvr7lTb3bafvBMXITIjgNDTjDVGhIAlxJBOuotGJ1NxCkTgktCKFGuVI1FPgHE9kJxcs4UopTAnTiAz7I37oYLeChhU1X3dZZSLL5C3w1WotqdL@E4/C7b8).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ó      # Get a list of the prime factorization of the (implicit) input-integer
 0K    # Remove all 0s
   {   # Sort it (from lowest to highest)
    R  # Reverse it (from highest to lowest)
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 71 bytes

```
f=\(n,m=2,l=0)`if`(n%%m,-sort(-c(if(l)l,if(n>1)f(n,m+1))),f(n/m,m,l+1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGq4sz0vMSS0qJU26WlJWm6Fjfd02xjNPJ0cm2NdHJsDTQTMtMSNPJUVXN1dIvzi0o0dJM1MtM0cjRzdIBUnp2hZhpIsbahpqamDpCpn6uTq5MD4kKNS4NboGGmqaCsYKhgyIUQMjQCiRmhiBmZgMSMgSqRBI0NoJpRlBqbQbQbcUFsW7AAQgMA)

Recursive function that directly calculates prime exponents, and sorts them on every recursive call (which is unneccessary except for the outermost call, so overflows the stack for large inputs).

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>74</s> 67 bytes

*Edit: -7 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
\(n,`?`=\(n,m)if(n>1)`if`(n%%m,n?m+1,c(m,n/m?m)))-sort(-table(n?2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGq4sz0vMSS0qJU26WlJWm6FjedYzTydBLsE2xBdK5mZppGnp2hZkJmWoJGnqpqrk6efa62oU6yBpCln2ufq6mpqVucX1SioVuSmJSTqpFnb6SpCTVqT3JiiQbcAg0zTR2lmDwlTQVlBUMFQy5USUMjhKwRhqyRCULWGKgbTdrYAMVoDO3GZsiGG2FYbWxiiqTCDGwCxA8LFkBoAA)

Uses recursive helper function `?` to calculate prime factors, and then sorts their exponents a single time (and thus copes with much larger inputs, but at the expense of 3 more bytes of code).

Comment: How about renaming the helper function in the second approach for [-7 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGq4sz0vMSS0qJU26WlJWm6FjedYzTydBLsE2xBdK5mZppGnp2hZkJmWoJGnqpqrk6efa62oU6yBpCln2ufq6mpqVucX1SioVuSmJSTqpFnb6SpCTVqT3JiiQbcAg0zTR2lmDwlTQVlBUMFQy5USUMjhKwRhqyRCULWGKgbTdrYAMVoDO3GZsiGG2FYbWxiiqTCDGwCxA8LFkBoAA)?

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 59 bytes

```
.+
$*
m(+`\A(1+)(\1)+$
$1¶$#2
(?=(¶.+))(\1)+$
¶$#2
1A`
O^#`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxbsJAEEX7dw0bac0itDO7HtZFhFxRcgGEnCIFBRQoZ/MBfDFnIEnxR1/z/3/Pr@/b43PdhNO07iPtlnuI02UMErtwkS62tLLMbaOE40dY5n3s/oPft4wT52szrcvMbhWUTKHHOFAZkIQI4sWC9IghFU2oVwvaowe0khPZp0ZJFKUM9E4xzDmJ6oTkIH2RHDIY@pqWTHbZ2ychv1PN5e8aNddqqf4A) Outputs prime signature on separate lines but link is to test suite that joins on commas for convenience. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
m(`
```

Run the rest of the script in multiline mode where `$` matches at the end of any line.

```
+`\A(1+)(\1)+$
$1¶$#2
```

Repeatedly extract the smallest prime factor of the input number. (`$#2` is actually one less than the smallest prime factor but it's consistent and we only care about the multiplicities anyway.) As this is slow for large numbers the test suite omits some of the slower cases.

```
(?=(¶.+))(\1)+$
¶$#2
```

Get the multiplicities of each factor.

```
1A`
```

Remove the `1` remaining after all of the prime factors have been extracted.

```
O^#`
```

Sort the multiplicities in descending numeric order.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 12 bytes

```
__\:~@{:@q:]
```

Independently found, but essentially a port of [Adám's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256150/110888). An exact port would be `1\:~@{__ q:]`, at 12 bytes as well.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY-xSkNBEEV7v-JgYQyYsDM7u293gxIIWFlZG1IEH2IjglZCfiTNs7DzB-z8Df8mY14GZi4z93Jg9p_Pw8_5fNJz3ZhwRaB5z-as7u9uv97f-ln53mwe2m750ZavbT2e_n6nZ4_bpxcu-8VuPb24QVAiiQ4RjIomrCIqZCQghiR8K6hn3I0WXRE_BLQgmeJhd9SC4wwLJCNlYsCUnOkCUd2KxCPiH-3smlFfRaOdZj5JR5LOquNLLCWHQj2WjH8Mw6gH)

```
__\:~@{:@q:]
__       q:]  NB. find prime exponents excluding zero
      {:@     NB. take the tail of the result
  \:~@        NB. descending sort the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

-6 thanks to @Shaggy

```
k ü mÊñn
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ayD8IG3K8W4&input=Njg2MA)

```
k ü mÊñn
k        Get the prime factors of the input
  ü      Group the factors to lists of the same element
    mÊ   Map each group to its length
      ñn Sort them in descending order
```

Comment: [A quick 8-byter](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ayD8IG3K8c0&input=Njg2MA)

Comment: You can also golf your version down to [11 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=awriIKPotljDzXc&input=Njg2MA)

Comment: Thanks @Shaggy. Took me a little while to understand the 8-byte version but I think I got it. So it groups the factors, gets the length of each, and sorts them using the `n` function?

Comment: Rough explanation: Get the prime factors, group & sort, map lengths and sort by subtracting from 2 (in my version) or by negating (in the version you posted).

Comment: @Shaggy - Can you explain why `ñÍ` sorts them by subtracting from 2? I realize that `Í` is a shortcut for `n2`, but I don't see how the `2` gets passed to `n`. Also, I thought my version was equivalent to `.sort((a,b)=>b-a)`, is that what you mean by negating or is it doing something else? Thanks.

Comment: Unlike `n`, which is the direct equivalent of JavaScript's `sort`, `ñ` first applies any method passed to it as an argument to each _individual_ element in the array and then sorts. So, in your version, the `n` is negating each individual element (e.g., `[1,2,3]` to `[-1,-2,-3]`) and then sorting. As to `Í`: if you have a look at the transpiled JS, you'll see that the `n` and the `2` are passed as 2 individual arguments and, as the `n` method can take an argument itself, it "consumes" the `2`.

Comment: Both your version and mine result in the _exact_ same result, sorting the array in descending order, but using `Í` over `n` is a good habit to get into as it saves a byte if you're using more methods afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
↔OmLgp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbFP9cn/SC////GxoZm5iaAQA)

```
     p  # get the prime factors
    g   # group identical elements
  mL    # get the length of each group
        # (these are the prime exponents)
 O      # sort into ascending order
↔       # and reverse
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Gave Jacob my initial solution, so here's an alternative.

```
k òÎmÊÍÔ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ayDyzm3KzdQ&input=Njg2MA)

```
k òÎmÊÍÔ     :Implicit input of integer
k            :Prime factors
  ò          :Partition between elements where
   Î         :  The sign of their differences is truthy (non-zero)
    m        :Map
     Ê       :  Length
      Í      :Sort
       Ô     :Reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 45 bytes

```arturo
$=>[factors.prime&|tally|values|sort|reverse]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?3mO3XD)

Comment: Not sure what happens when ran on a real machine, but when I try the testcase `1` it times out, which would not be an acceptable output

Comment: @Samathingamajig Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 7 bytes

```
fCf:)-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy5CsJQEEX78ycWwpvlbbZ@hJWNkICQxkgq8dufY8gUc7kL57Gty/R@bdP4rM8xX@fL6Xwf39syBMXIVERwOprxjqhQkIQ4kgnX0NhEa26hSAQJbUihxTga9RQ4xxPZyQVLuFIKNWEalWE74o8Odi9oWFHz45dDKlmq98A3a62kRt9Pfg)

```
fC   # Prime factors
f:   # Count occurrences 
)-]  # Map-Take counts
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 5 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.12 bytes

```
Zhwz;
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLozLKq6whbKjQgmWGRsYmpmYQHgA)

##### Explanation

```python
Zhwz;  # Implicit input
Zh     # Prime factor exponents
  w    # Without zeros
   z;  # Reverse-sorted
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 97 bytes

```
A=[2...n]
P=A[∑_{N=3}^A0^{mod(A,N-1)}=0]
L=log_P(gcd(n,P^n))
F=L.sort[L.length...1]
f(n)=F[F>0]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n93kmv3xwq)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ctrilb7bf4)

This theoretically works for all inputs \$\le19998\$, but in reality, because of floating point issues, this only works for numbers up to around \$15\$ or so.

Below is a version that works for all numbers up to \$19998\$, at the cost of a few bytes:

#### 133 bytes

```
A=join([1....5n],n)
P=A[∑_{N=2}^{floor(A^{.5})}0^{mod(A,N)}=0]
L=log_P(gcd(n,P^{floor(log_Pn)}))
F=L.sort[L.length...1]
f(n)=F[F>0]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/12zffc7pyg)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vgwvdmqoo6)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
òT║≥Q{U
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9554baf2517b55&i=6860&m=2)

This is a packed stax program which unpacks to the following 8 bytes:

```
|n0-or|u
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Cn0-or%7Cu&i=6860&m=2)

## Explanation

```
|n       # list of prime exponents
  0-     # remove 0s
    o    # sort
     r   # reverse
      |u # uneval (print array as array)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

Golfed vesrion, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/NNii1LLWoONUhOL@oJNonsbhE38EtMbkkv8gzryQ1PbXIQTlW7X9atJmFmUGsvn5AUWZeyX8A)

```
f=Reverse@Sort[Last/@FactorInteger@#]&
```

Ungolfed version

```
PrimeSignature[n_Integer] := Module[{factorization, exponents},
  factorization = FactorInteger[n];
  exponents = Last /@ factorization;
  Sort[exponents]//Reverse
]

PrimeSignature[6860]//Print
```